# Mongoose search subcategories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck with this one, been struggling for 2 days, tried a lot of things, but it just doesn't work.

So I have db from this json

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5172d1daffdd81f3234d5f88"
},
"categories": [{
        "categories": [{
                "id": "mens-clothing-suits",
                "image": "categories/mens-clothing-suits.jpg",
                "name": "Suits",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's suits for business or pleasure. Enjoy from a variety of different styles and cuts.",
                "page_title": "Mens Suits for Business and Casual",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-clothing",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-clothing-jackets",
                "image": "categories/mens-clothing-sportscoats.png",
                "name": "Jackets & Coats",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's Jackets, Coats & Outerwear. Classic outdoor-tested garments with traditional styling details that provide comfort, insulation and ease of movement, whatever the weather.",
                "page_title": "Men's Jackets Including Jackets & Blazzers",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-clothing",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-clothing-dress-shirts",
                "image": "categories/mens-clothing-dress-shirts.jpg",
                "name": "Dress Shirts",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's dress shirts in a variety of colors and styles including striped, button down, non-iron & more",
                "page_title": "Men's Dress Shirts including Striped, Button Down, Non-Iron & More",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-clothing",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-clothing-shorts",
                "image": "categories/mens-clothing-shorts.png",
                "name": "Shorts",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's spring shorts in cotton. Variety of different fits.",
                "page_title": "Men's Spring Shorts",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-clothing",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-clothing-pants",
                "image": "categories/mens-clothing-pants.png",
                "name": "Pants",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's Trousers. Practical, easy-to-wear styles wherever you're headed. Check out famous rugged, long-lasting trousers, jeans, cargo pants and more.",
                "page_title": "Men's Pants Including Khakis, Cargos, Trousers, Jeans & More",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-clothing",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }
        ],
        "id": "mens-clothing",
        "image": "categories/mens-clothing-accessories.jpg",
        "name": "Clothing",
        "page_description": "Shop Men's Clothing. Relaxed, timeless classics you can rely on; from denim to corduroys and sweaters to shirts. Huge range of contemporary colours and eco-aware designs: great casualwear.",
        "page_title": "Mens Clothing Including Suits, Tops, Bottoms & More",
        "parent_category_id": "mens",
        "c_showInMenu": true
    }, {
        "categories": [{
                "id": "mens-accessories-ties",
                "image": "categories/mens-accessories-ties.png",
                "name": "Ties",
                "page_description": "Shop Mens's Ties for all occasions including business or casual.",
                "page_title": "Men's Casual and Business Ties",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-accessories",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-accessories-gloves",
                "name": "Gloves",
                "page_description": "Shop Men'sGloves. Versatile, commuter, boot, oxford, deer and resolve gloves. All with famous long-lasting quality.",
                "page_title": "Men's Gloves",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-accessories",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }, {
                "id": "mens-accessories-luggage",
                "image": "categories/mens-accessories-luggage.jpg",
                "name": "Luggage",
                "page_description": "Shop Men's Wheeled Luggage. Versatile, rugged suitcases, baggage, holdalls and shoulder bags. All with famous long-lasting quality.",
                "page_title": "Men's Wheeled Luggage",
                "parent_category_id": "mens-accessories",
                "c_showInMenu": true
            }
        ],
        "id": "mens-accessories",
        "name": "Accessories",
        "page_description": "Shop mens accessories including belts, wallets. gloves, hats, watches, luggage & more.",
        "page_title": "Men's Accessories Belts, Wallets. Gloves, Hats, Watches, Luggage & More",
        "parent_category_id": "mens",
        "c_showInMenu": true
    }
],
"id": "mens",
"name": "Mens",
"page_description": "Men's range. Hard-wearing boots, jackets and clothing for unbeatable comfort day in, day out. Practical, easy-to-wear styles wherever you're headed.",
"page_title": "Men's Footwear, Outerwear, Clothing & Accessories",
"parent_category_id": "root",
"c_showInMenu": true
}
```

I created a model in mongoose which look like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubcategoriesSchema = new Schema({
    id:String,
    image:String,
    name: String,
    page_description:String,
    page_title: String,
    parent_category_id: String,
    c_showInMenu:Boolean
});

const CategoriesSchema = new Schema({
    id:String,
    image:String,
    name: String,
    page_description:String,
    page_title: String,
    parent_category_id: String,
    c_showInMenu:Boolean,
    categories:[SubcategoriesSchema]
});

//create schema
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    id:String,
    image:String,
    name: String,
    page_description:String,
    page_title: String,
    parent_category_id: String,
    c_showInMenu:Boolean,
    categories:[CategoriesSchema]
});

mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema);
mongoose.model('categories', CategoriesSchema);
mongoose.model('subCategories', SubcategoriesSchema);
```

What I need to do is to get the contents of category with its subcategories and display it on my page, so in my app I do this

```
app.get('/mens/:id', (req, res) => {
    Category.find({})
        .populate('categories')
        .find({'categories.id': req.params.id})
        .exec(categories => {          
            res.render('categories/categories', {
                categories_list:categories,
                result:req.params.id,
                sex: 'mens'
            });
            console.log(categories);
        })
});
```

And here's what I get

```
mens-clothing CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ categories: [ { id: 'mens-clothing-suits', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-suits.jpg', name: 'Suits', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s suits for business or pleasure. Enjoy from a variety of different styles and cuts.', page_title: 'Mens Suits for Business and Casual', parent_category_id: 'mens-clothing', c_showInMenu: true }, { id: 'mens-clothing-jackets', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-sportscoats.png', name: 'Jackets & Coats', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s Jackets, Coats & Outerwear. Classic outdoor-tested garments with traditional styling details that provide comfort, insulation and ease of movement, whatever the weather.', page_title: 'Men\'s Jackets Including Jackets & Blazzers', parent_category_id: 'mens-clothing', c_showInMenu: true }, { id: 'mens-clothing-dress-shirts', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-dress-shirts.jpg', name: 'Dress Shirts', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s dress shirts in a variety of colors and styles including striped, button down, non-iron & more', page_title: 'Men\'s Dress Shirts including Striped, Button Down, Non-Iron & More', parent_category_id: 'mens-clothing', c_showInMenu: true }, { id: 'mens-clothing-shorts', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-shorts.png', name: 'Shorts', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s spring shorts in cotton. Variety of different fits.', page_title: 'Men\'s Spring Shorts', parent_category_id: 'mens-clothing', c_showInMenu: true }, { id: 'mens-clothing-pants', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-pants.png', name: 'Pants', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s Trousers. Practical, easy-to-wear styles wherever you\'re headed. Check out famous rugged, long-lasting trousers, jeans, cargo pants and more.', page_title: 'Men\'s Pants Including Khakis, Cargos, Trousers, Jeans & More', parent_category_id: 'mens-clothing', c_showInMenu: true } ], id: 'mens-clothing', image: 'categories/mens-clothing-accessories.jpg', name: 'Clothing', page_description: 'Shop Men\'s Clothing. Relaxed, timeless classics you can rely on; from denim to corduroys and sweaters to shirts. Huge range of contemporary colours and eco-aware designs: great casualwear.', page_title: 'Mens Clothing Including Suits, Tops, Bottoms & More', parent_category_id: 'mens', c_showInMenu: true }" at path "_id" for model "category"
```

How can I search by categories id and do it right? I read that the problem has smth to do with _id object, but I have only one _id in my database. How can I search by that other id field, like if I need to retrieve "mens-clothing" or "mens-accessories-ties"? I'm so confused pls help.

Comment: You don't need to call `.populate()` here as the data is already embedded in the document. You clearly did not create the data with mongoose and mongoose interchanges `id` and `_id` treating them as the same thing, hence the cast error. You can add `{ _id: false }` as a schema option to every schema to get rid of the errors